# How can i create a structure in MPI, that contains self referential fields?

Tags: tree, mpi, self-reference

I want to create a binary tree, for which i need to be able to refer to the structure from within itself.

The tree is of the form

```
    struct tree
    {
     int val; 
     struct tree *lchild, *rchild;
    };
```

How can i do this in MPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pointer type in MPI - it would not make any sense. MPI processes have totally separate address spaces, thus a pointer would be useless when transferred to another rank.

You should fundamentally rethink your data structure with respect to distributed computing. I can't give a general recommendation without many more details about the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to implement a binary tree in MPI without having to use an array of size (2^height_of_corresponding_tree+1)?

Comment: In MPI, usually no single node contains the entire set of data (e.g. tree) and you try to avoid sending around large chunks of data regularly as well. So what you have to think about is how you process the data and how you distribute it. There is no single solution here as a replacement for a tree.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of question comes up [a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmpi%5D+pointer+struct) here, to the point that we should probably try to write a canonical question.

As Zulan notes, pointers aren't meaningful outside the process in which the memory was allocated, so this can't be done in general.  Forget about MPI for a moment and simply imagine writing the data to disk - the pointer values alone wouldn't be of any help in reconstructing the tree structure.

But tree and graph structures are quite useful and are widely used even in distributed memory computing, so you need a way of representing the data that can be serialized (over the network to another process, or to disk) that is relatively efficient *for* *your* *use-case*.

If your structure is very dynamic - including height (or degree, for graph) changes - it might make sense to keep the data in memory in the linked-tree type representation and just serialize the chunks that need to be sent into an array as the need arises.  If on the other hand the structure of the tree remains relatively stable, it may make sense to keep the data in the array representation even for the computations.

Either way, you'll need to be able to serialize the data in some meaningful way.  Sticking with binary trees, consider the following:

```
            A
           / \
          /   \
         B     E
        / \   / \
       C   . .   F
      / \       / \
     D   .     .   .
    / \
   .   .
```

There are a number of ways you could represent this in a linear array; which one is best depends on what you need.

First, you have to decide whether to represent the complete binary tree (all 2^(height+1)-1 nodes) or only those nodes that are present, with explicit null nodes at the end of a tree representing the ends of subtrees; the first is faster and is more space efficient *if* your tree is going to be close to full and balanced, and gives the advantage of being able to explicitly calculate indices of children or parents given a nodes index, where the second is more space efficient if not but you loose the explicit calculability advantage.  (These pros and cons are the same for, say, dense vs sparse matrix representation; it's a common set of tradeoffs).  In the below I'm assuming you're not representing a full binary tree.

Then you have to decide how to convert position in a tree into position into the linear order of an array; the canonical representations are pre-order:

```
A B C D . . . . E . F . .
```

or in-order

```
. D . C . B . A . E . F .
```

or post-order

```
. . D . C . B . . . F E A
```

The three keep subtrees contiguous, which is nice for sending them around; pre-order is nice for a lot of applications because it makes it easy to find subtrees, but the ordering you use should match the ordering in which you'd be using/searching the data.

But the best decisions for the various choices - full vs sparse representation, method for calculating the linear ordering, and whether to use the array representation as the native representation for the calculations vs just serializing into that representation for communication - all come down to how you'll be using the structures.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!